# Git not working and asking for unknown password

Tags: git, github, ssh, dns

My git is having a lot of issues lately. 5 days ago it was working perfectly and now, I can't do anything with it. When I am trying to clone `/` push whatever, git is asking me for a password that I do not have (for example if I try to clone `git@bitbucket.org/name/project.git`, git is asking me for git@bitbucket.org's password. Also every first time that I try to clone, this message appears:

---

```
WARNING: POSSIBLE DNS SPOOFING DETECTED!          @

The ECDSA host key for bitbucket.org has changed,
and the key for the corresponding IP address ***.***.***.**
is unknown. This could either mean that
DNS SPOOFING is happening or the IP address for the host
and its host key have changed at the same time.

WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!

IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the ECDSA key sent by the remote host is
**********************************.
Please contact your system administrator.
Add correct host key in ***********/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Offending ECDSA key in ***********/.ssh/known_hosts:1
ECDSA host key for bitbucket.org has changed and you have requested strict checking.
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

---

I am working on Windows and I already tried to reinstall git, use some new ssh keys but no changes.

I really have no idea from where this error is comming from.
Thanks !

Comment: Did you add your new SSH keys in the BitBucket backend? Did you maybe clone via https:// instead of SSH before? Also there might be something wrong with the IP of bitbucket.org. Which IP do you get when you do a ping bitbucket.org ? (for me it is 131.103.20.168 / 131.103.20.167)

Comment: Yes I did add my new keys in Bitbucket (also in Github, which produces the same errors than Bitbucket). I tried https and ssh and both are not working. The ip that I get for bitbucket is 148.163.189.23. I don't know if it is the good one or not...

Comment: Did you try to delete the line one in .ssh/known_hosts ? I have no clue what is the cause for a changed host key and you should be careful. You might want to compare the fingerprints to those in https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/use-the-ssh-protocol-with-bitbucket-221449711.html (search for the text "The public key fingerprints for the Bitbucket server are" in that link)